# When should I deallocate memory, if all?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiwebview, memory-management

I’ve read all the iOS memory allocation/deallocation basics, but can’t find anything on the following:

I’ve created a small app, that pretty much lists a grid of UIButtons and clicking on any of those, it adds a UIScrollView to the current controller view (and adds a bunch of UIView and UIWebView’s inside etc).

On adding the UIScrollVIew, I also add a UIButton, that takes me back to the "home grid" and then removes the UIScrollView from the superview.
I release all the things I’m retaining/allocating etc and when I check the app with Instruments, it doesn’t show any memory leak.

But every time I tap on any of the UIButton objects, I allocate more memory (according to Instruments) and it keeps growing – and "reopening" the same kind of UIScrollView from a button always adds more memory allocations.

If I simulate a memory warning in the simulator, it deallocated a bit of the memory and I can then keep growing it again.

So here’s my question: should I bother with trying to deallocate this somehow manually? And if so, where should I actually do this? I’m quite new to Obj-C, so I think I have most of the basics covered, but more advanced topics still require some help.

Creating the grid:

```
UIScrollView *grid = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[[self view] addSubview:grid];
[grid release];
```

Adding buttons (in a for loop):

```
UIButton *slotItem = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((float) slotWidth * j), ((float) slotHeight * i), (float) slotWidth, (float)slotHeight)];
[grid addSubview:slotItem];

UIWebView *buttonWebThumb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, slotWidth, slotHeight)];

[buttonWebThumb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[buttonWebThumb setOpaque:NO];

[buttonWebThumb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", htmlTop, [[row objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:1], htmlBottom] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
buttonWebThumb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[slotItem addSubview:buttonWebThumb];
buttonWebThumb.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
buttonWebThumb.exclusiveTouch = NO;
[buttonWebThumb release];

[slotItem addTarget:self action:@selector(showPages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[slotItem release];
```

showPages method then creates another UIScrollView and adds 1-10 separate UIWebView’s in there and adds a “close” button to the new UIScrollView.

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you show some code. However, you _never_ want to deallocate any objects yourself, this will happen automatically when the retain count reaches zero. If it doesn't happen, some object still holds a reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably seeing this because you aren't removing all elements from the view before leaving it.

For example, if you exit the view with a method like this, do this:

```
- (id) viewExitAction: (id) sender {
  id elem;
  for(elem in buttons) {
    [elem removeSelfFromView];
  }
  // etc
}
```

This will automatically decrease the retain counts of these objects down to zero. (Provided you added them to the view and then released them, as you're supposed to.)

Otherwise, the `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc` methods never get called.

Comment: Are you saying that I should then remove all the subview’s I’ve added to all UIScrollView’s I create when I remove the UIScrollView from the current controller?

Answer (score 2):

Dealloc is invoked indirectly through the release method, and you should never call it directly.[NSObject Manual on dealloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)